# Determining if a set is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We just started learning vector spaces and I have no idea how to begin solving this problem.  I'm asked to determine if the following is a vector space and if it is not I'm then asked to identify at least one of the ten vector space axioms that fails.

The set

{$\left( x, y\right): x\ge 0, y$ is a real number }

with the standard operations in $R^2$

Comment: Start by listing the 10 axioms for a vector space, and then start checking them.

Comment: Here is a nice link with some examples on checking vector space axioms. Perhaps you will find it helpful: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/321358-linear-algebra-primer-part-1-vector-spaces/

Comment: Is the field taken to be the reals?

Comment: @T.Bongers I have the axioms listed in my book.  I just don't know how to apply them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the inverse elements of addition property, stating that for an element $v\in V$, where $V$ is your vector space, there exists an element $-v\in V$ such that $v+(-v) = \bf 0$ $ = (0,0)$ (where $\bf 0$ is the identity element). Take a sample $v$ to be $v = (2,-3)$, is there a $-v\in V$ such that the sum becomes $\bf 0$?

Comment: In your example would $(-2, 3)$ be the $-v$?

Comment: Yes, good, that is indeed the only vector that will result in (0,0), but is $-v$ in your vector space? If not, we have found a counterexample, giving us the answer we are after.